# Prove that there is no rational function in $F(x)$ such that its square is $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, rational-functions

I came across this homework problem and honestly have no idea where to begin.

> Prove that there is no rational function in $F(x)$ such that its square is $x$.

First of all, I am confused about the notation. I'm accustomed to seeing $F(x)$ denote the field $F$ adjoined with some element $x$, but $x$ is not defined here.

My only thought was to take $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, then have $\left(\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right)^2=\frac{g(x)^2}{h(x)^2}$, which doesn't get very far.

A hint on how to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hint:  if $g(x)$ has degree $p$ and $h(x)$ has degree $q$, then what are the degrees of $(g(x))^2$ and the degree of $x(h(x))^2$?

Comment: We get $\deg(g(x))^2=2p$ and $\deg x(h(x))^2 = 2q+1$.

Comment: Right.  So, how can the two be equal, since $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative integers...?

Comment: Isn't it impossible? If we want $2p=2q+1$, then $p=q+1/2$, which doesn't make sense in terms of degrees.

Comment: Exactly.  So, there is your proof by contradiction.  For if such a rational function $(g(x)/h(x))^2 = x$, then we would require such a condition to hold on their degrees.  But this is impossible, hence no such rational function exists.

Comment: Ah, I see! Great, thanks for all your help!